# Sort results of get()

Tags: javascript, nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a CouchDB document that I want to output ordered by `"date"`:

```
{
  "_id": "accounts",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "_name.1",
      "date": 1524336565172
    },
    {
      "name": "_name.2",
      "date": 1524336565173
    },
    {
      "name": "_name.3",
      "date": 1524336565171
    }
}
```

Right now I'm using the following PouchDB, which populates a `<ul>`, but obviously not in the correct order:

```
localDB.get('accounts').then(function(result){
  $.each(result.accounts, function(i, value) {
    $('ul').append('<li data-date="' + value.date + '">' + value.name + '</li>');
  });
});
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
<li data-date="1524336565171">_name.3</li>
<li data-date="1524336565172">_name.1</li>
<li data-date="1524336565173">_name.2</li>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>CouchDB indexing works if you have multiple documents and you intend to sort docs based on document fields. You have a **single** document, therefore you cannot use CouchDB indexing and you have to sort the fields in your code logic.</s>

It might be more practical to have mulitple documents, rather than keeping all your data inside just a single document.

You can breakup your single document, into multiple documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": "account 001",
  "name": "_name.1",
  "date": 1524336565172
}

{
  "_id": "account 002",
  "name": "_name.2",
  "date": 1524336565173
}

{
  "_id": "account 003",
  "name": "_name.3",
  "date": 1524336565171
}
```

Then you can create a view function in CouchDB and get documents indexed/sorted by the `date` field like below:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.date && doc.name){
    emit(doc.date, doc.name);
  }
}
```

The above view can be created with PouchDB. You can use [Map/reduce queries](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) or you can use  [Mango queries](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html).

Comment: Thanks @user3405291. Is your proposed document structure generally considered better practice than what I was using - or just in this case? If I want to adopt your structure and naming - is there any way to 'auto-increment' the `_id`s (account 004, account 005, etc.)? Something better than cutting of the last three digits from every document and finding the highest value?

Comment: @TonaldDrump Having multiple documents is the way to go with `NoSQL` databases. Since that way, you can sort/index your documents according to any document fields you like.

Comment: @TonaldDrump Yes, you can auto-increment the doc `_id`. To do so, you can use the PouchDB API for [creating documents](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document "Create/update a document").  Inside your JavaScript code, you can modify any document field as you wish. For example you can have something like: `... db.put({
  _id: id++,
  name: nextName, date: nextDate
}) ...` which increments the `_id` inside a loop. You just need to implement that loop in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Regarding your last point: I meant an auto increment when coming back later. To increment the `id` I'd first have to run a get to somehow get the highest document id currently in use. Or is there another way?

Comment: @TonaldDrump I think you want to increment the `_id` on an existing document, if that's the case, you need to get the previous `_id` and increment it. Please note that for updating an existing document, you need to get `_rev` too, as [mentioned in documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/api.html#revisions).

Answer (score 1):

While @user3405291's answer is generally considered better practice, you could also keep your existing document structure and create a [view](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html) from your single accounts document:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.accounts) {
    doc.accounts.forEach(function(account) {
      emit(account.date, account.name);
    });
  }
}
```

For storing accounts, I'd strongly recommend using a document per account as proposed by the other answer, though. It's much easier to scale, because accounts can then be updated/deleted independently.